# MVC Model validation with bootstrap in ajax submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working in a MVC application. I am validating the form fields by using mvc model data annotations.
  like below.

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I am just using this model in my page and I am submitting my form by using `$.ajax` 
I am using the below method to get the validation errors while submitting through ajax.

```
public class AjaxValidationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            //base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
            if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                return;

            var modelState = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState;

            if (!modelState.IsValid)
            {
                var errorModel = from x in modelState.Keys
                                 where modelState[x].Errors.Count > 0
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     key = x,
                                     errors = modelState[x].Errors.Select(t => t.ErrorMessage).ToArray()
                                 };
                filterContext.Result = new JsonResult()
                {
                    Data = new { Errors = errorModel }
                };

                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;



            }
        }
    }
```

And my action method will be,

```
        [HttpPost]
        [AjaxValidation]
        public ActionResult SaveCustomer(CustomerViewModel CommentViewModel)
        {
            return Json("Customer added successfully");
        }
```

I am just calling the above method from `$.ajax` like below

```
function saveCustomer() {

    var customerViewModel = {};

    customerViewModel.Name = $('#txtName').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Customer/SaveCustomer',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(customerViewModel),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

            if (data.Errors != undefined) {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.Errors.length; i++) {
                    // Getting error list in data.Errors
                }
            }
        }
    });
};
```

I am getting the error in `data.Errors` object and I can able to get the field name and error message. 
  Here I just want to show this error message for the text box. like, bootstrap formvalidation (http://formvalidation.io/examples/changing-tooltip-position/).

How can I show the error messages like bootstrap formvalidation?

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: are you actually using formvalidation.io's library or you just want some code that behaves similarly when there's an error?

Comment: Shyju, I am not getting any error here. I just want to show the validation messages as bootstrap tooltip. like this http://formvalidation.io/examples/changing-tooltip-position/

Comment: Stephen, I am not using exact formvalidation.io js. I just want to show the validation messages like that.